# External RSS not working with sharepoint web part

Tags: sharepoint

Our application expose certain rss as
http://myservername/feeeds/feedid=110. This link works with with all browser and i am able to see rss.

But when i provide same URL to our sharepoint web part, it gives me error and not able to get headlines.

Answer (score 1):

I would double check the security of the feed. If it requires any sort of authentication (windows, forms, etc.), it will fail in the normal SharePoint web part.

Comment: There is no authentication involved here.

Comment: There is no authentication required. This works with browser very well.

Answer (score 1):

If your application is on the SharePoint server then you're probably running into the Loopback check, which prevents http access from the server to itself using an other name than the real servername.

If this is the case then you can see how to disable the loopback check in this [kb](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861)

Comment: I believe our URL  http://myservername/feeeds/feedid=110 works with browser because browser process this request and get feed URL but normal RSS reader/viewer expect RSS (XML) file and don't process request and thus give us error.